# How do i filter all results of a one to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

Imagine the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE item (code string);
CREATE TABLE item_event (id int, item_code string, event int, date smalldatetime);

item:
code
item1
item2
item3
item4

item_event:
id | item_code  | event | date
1  |  item1     | 123   | 2021-05-04 05:50
2  |  item1     | 456   | 2021-05-04 06:50
3  |  item2     | 123   | 2021-05-04 05:50
4  |  item2     | 678   | 2021-05-04 08:50
5  |  item3     | 456   | 2021-05-04 05:50
6  |  item3     | 890   | 2021-05-04 09:50
7  |  item4     | 123   | 2021-05-04 11:50
8  |  item4     | 456   | 2021-05-04 20:50
9  |  item4     | 890   | 2021-05-04 01:50
```

How do I select the items that have no 456 event or a 456 event whose date is after a 890 event if it has one?

So in this case it would return `item2` and `item4`.

Can't figure out how to do it in SQL. Everything i have tried just filters out the individual event instead of looking at a set "grouped by item_code."

Comment: Look into `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Do you want just the `item` or also all its `item_event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods of doing this, though which depends on what question you're trying to answer. The first is with a `NOT EXISTS`, which would likely be better for your first scenario (no `456` events). Which would look like this:

```sql
SELECT Code
FROM dbo.Item I
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Item_Event IE
                  WHERE IE.Item_Code = I.Code
                    AND IE.Event = 456);
```

The latter would be to us a `HAVING` with conditional aggregation, which is likely more suited to your second requirement, due to the need to compare 2 different events:

```sql
SELECT I.Code
FROM dbo.Item
     JOIN dbo.Item_Event IE ON I.Code = IE.Item_Code --This *might* need to be a LEFT JOIN
GROUP BY I.Code
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Event = 456 THEN 1 END) = 0
    OR MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 890 THEN date END) < MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 456 THEN Date END);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregation we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT item_code
    FROM item_event
    GROUP BY item_code
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN event = 456 THEN 1 END) = 0 OR
           MIN(CASE WHEN event = 890 THEN date END) <
           MIN(CASE WHEN event = 456 THEN date END)
)

SELECT *
FROM item_event
WHERE item_code IN (SELECT item_code FROM cte);
```

### Demo

The logic of the above `HAVING` clause is to retain any `item_code` set of records having *no* 456 event at all, *or* any `item_code` where its earliest 890 event occurs *before* the earliest 456 event.  In this case, that would mean that every 456 event had at least one earlier prior 890 event.

Comment: OK...but the solution you accepted features an incorrect first query, and a second query which is identical to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typical 'nested negation' exercise.
The problem becomes easier to express in SQL when you rephrase it as follows:

- Give me every item that does *not* have

  - a 456 event that is *not* accompanied by

    - a 890 event with a date before 456's

Each indentation becomes a subquery. The negations are expressed by `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.

```sql
DROP TABLE item IF EXISTS 
DROP TABLE item_event IF EXISTS 
CREATE TABLE item (code string)
CREATE TABLE item_event (id int, item_code string, event int, date smalldatetime)
INSERT INTO item VALUES ('item1'), ('item2'), ('item3'), ('item4')
INSERT INTO item_event VALUES
    (1, 'item1', 123, '2021-05-04 05:50'),
    (2, 'item1', 456, '2021-05-04 06:50'),
    (3, 'item2', 123, '2021-05-04 05:50'),
    (4, 'item2', 678, '2021-05-04 08:50'),
    (5, 'item3', 456, '2021-05-04 05:50'),
    (6, 'item3', 890, '2021-05-04 09:50'),
    (7, 'item4', 123, '2021-05-04 11:50'),
    (8, 'item4', 456, '2021-05-04 20:50'),
    (9, 'item4', 890, '2021-05-04 01:50')

SELECT *
FROM item
WHERE code NOT IN (
    SELECT ie456.item_code
    FROM item_events ie456
    WHERE ie456.event = 456
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM item_events ie890
        WHERE ie890.item_code = ie456.item_code
        AND ie890.event = 890
        AND ie890.date >= ie456.date
    )
)
```

Output:

```
item2
item4
```